# "E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages" after long time without using ubuntu

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, update-manager

After months of not using ubuntu, I turned on my PC and when I typed the usual apt-get update then upgrade,  a red icon showed on my panel and when I clicked to upgrade packages, the Software Updater was shown with no packages listed but 243,6 MB to be downloaded.

Even when I clicked on Install now, somehow Software Updater crashed.
And when I try to upgrade through terminal it shows "31 not upgraded'

What should I do to properly upgrade these packages?

EDIT

Here's the list of the non-upgraded packages

```
gcc-4.9-base gcc-4.9-base:i386 gimp gimp-data lib32gcc1 libgcc1 libgcc1:i386
 libgimp2.0 liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0
 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core
 libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-impress 
 libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-galaxy libreoffice-style-human
 libreoffice-writer libva1 libva1:i386 linux-image-generic
 oxideqt-codecs-extra pcsx2:i386 python3-uno
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to force the installation of the packages by :
 `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

**Note:**
dist-upgrade can be quite dangerous. It will install all pending updates, with their new dependencies. It could delete packages. It could leave you with a very broken system.

https://debian-administration.org/article/69/Some_upgrades_show_packages_being_kept_back

Maybe this helps:

First clean the local repository of retrieved package files:
`sudo apt-get clean`

And then fix broken dependencies:
`sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Made this both steps and nothing happened. 

`daniloffs@dfwired:~$ sudo apt-get -f install`
`Reading package lists... Done`
`Building dependency tree       `
`Reading state information... Done`
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.`

Comment: Can this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571326/how-do-i-resolve-the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies